# Applescript: bulk delete anniversary with custom label on all contacts that have it

Tags: ios, macos, applescript, contacts

Many years ago I manually edited hundreds of contact cards adding an anniversary with a custom label.

I now want to remove all this custom anniversary in bulk, but I'm having no luck as I'm unable to select the custom label.

I've tried this but of course it throws an error:

```
tell application "Contacts"
    set theLabel to "MyCustomLabel"
    delete (anniversary of people whose label starts with theLabel)
    save
end tell
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running? What version of **macOS** where you running when you added the custom label? Does the custom label actually show in the **Contacts** _application_?  Does it show in the **vCard** export of a _Person_ who has had it added? Please provide an actual example of what you added and how exactly you added it.

Comment: I'm running macOS 11.5.2, but I added this data years ago; it shows in the Contacts application and in the export as well. Example: https://ibb.co/tPN2L2d

Comment: You missed the part of my previous comment where I asked -- Please provide an actual example of what you added and how exactly you added it.

Comment: I hit enter by mistake, example: https://ibb.co/tPN2L2d
The way I added it is very simple, just click on add field --> more fields --> date, click on label (default="anniversary")--> custom label

Comment: There seams to be a misunderstanding here, I asked What version of **macOS** are you running? and you said macOS 11.5.2, but the screenshot and directions are not for **macOS Big Sur**. I now noticed you also tag the post with `ios`, however in **iOS** 14.8 the direction are not accurate as there is no **Anniversary** field to select. Also in the screenshot, which I believe is in **Italian**, _Iscrizione_ translates to _Registration_ at **Google Translate** not **Anniversary**. As there is too much confusion going on here, I'm done with this question except to say the following...

Comment: Export to **vCard** the target **People** with the _field_ you want removed, delete them from **Contacts**, then in **Terminal** using e.g. `sed` remove the unwanted _field_, then import the edited **vCards** back into **Contacts**.  Delete the target **People** with the _field_ you want removed in **Contacts** in **iOS** then sync the **iPhone** with your **Mac** to update the contacts on your **iPhone**.